# Notification won't display?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have the following code to display a notification with custom view:

```
private void showMediaPlayerNotification(){
        RemoteViews rm = new RemoteViews(getActivity().getPackageName(), R.layout.notif_media_player);
        Intent activity = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, activity,0);

        Notification notif =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
                              .setContent(rm).setContentIntent(pendingActivity)
                              .setOngoing(true)
                              .build();
        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);

    }
```

This is inside a fragment. The notification will be shown when the fragment goes into `onStop()` and will be removed in `onResume()` and `onDetach()`.

However, the notification isn't displayed.

**What is wrong here?**

This was run on a Samsung Galaxy S3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/chimp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <!-- Media Buttons -->
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cancel"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pause"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/previous"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide the content of your remoteview layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add `setSmallIcon(int drawable)`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Now, how do I respond to the buttons inside the remote view ? :)

Comment: You will need to use `setOnClickPendingIntent` on you remoteViews

Comment: great ! and can I access the `logo` ImageView from my RemoteView to change the image at run time ?

Comment: I don't think you can change it like that. I think you need to update the whole notification with the logo imageview being updated.

Comment: How does Google Play Music does it then ? :) I am certain they are using a custom view :)

Comment: Also, the notification cancels when I open the app again **but** if I swipe the app off from recents, it stays. Weird.

Comment: that is because you used `setOngoing(true)`. That prevents the app notification from being cleared

Comment: So, how do I handle that? I mean, when the app is swiped out, it should go away. :)

Comment: then use `setOngoing(false)`

Comment: It is a media player, mate :) How do you see that working out? :)

Comment: Do you mean swipe out from the recents? have you tried setAutoCancel()? And if it is a MediaPlayer why don't you set the notification from the service that you are using to play the music using `startForeground` and `stopForeground`

Comment: Help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475142/pendingintent-to-communicate-from-notification-how-to