# Notification RemoteView on click listener

Tags: android, android-service, android-pendingintent, android-remoteview

So, after a lot of head scratching, I am at my wit's end. I have a media player `RemoteViews` in my notification and I would like to be able to access the play, pause, previous and next buttons.

I know that `setOnClickPendingIntent()` will be used to communicate from the notification. However, I am left wondering how that will work.

Is it possible to let the service handle the clicks?

I have tried this, but in vain. I was trying to let me service handle the pause and resume of the player:

```
rm = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notif_media_player);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
        intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, PAUSE);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), PAUSE, intent, 0);
        rm.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.pause, pending);

        Notification notif =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                 .setOngoing(true)
                                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                 .setContent(rm)
                                 .build();

        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                                  .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
```

and my `IBinder` is null. If that makes a difference.

**How do I pause and play music from notification?**

Comment: Please stop deleting past questions -- this is at least your third on this topic. Buttons don't work in `RemoteViews` in a `Notification`, last I checked. You are supposed to use the [action buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Actions) associated with an expanded notification. `setPendingIntentTemplate()` is not relevant for your scenario, as you do not have a collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on `CommonsWare`'s recommendation:

```
        rm = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notif_media_player);
        Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
        Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);

        pauseIntent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, PAUSE);
        dismissIntent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, DISMISS);

        PendingIntent pause = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), PAUSE, pauseIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent dismiss = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), DISMISS, dismissIntent, 0);

        rm.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pause, pause);
        rm.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.dismiss, dismiss);

        Notification notif =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                 .setOngoing(true)
                                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                 .setContent(rm)
                                 .build();

        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                                  .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
```

Comment: Where do you handle/receive the intents?